# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: audioBuffer.subarray is not a function

Tags: javascript

According to this [library](https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs) documentation, I'm trying to use the `subarray()` function but I get always this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: audioBuffer.subarray is not a function`
This is the code I'm using to generate the arrayBuffer to use with the library. I've tried also to create `Int16Array` but without success.

```
const createChunksFromStream = (details) => {
  if(details.statusCode === 206){
    console.log(details);
    const headers = new Headers();
    details.responseHeaders.forEach( (header) => {
      headers.append(header.name, header.value);
    });
    const request = new Request(details.url, {method: 'GET', headers: headers})
    fetch(request)
    .then( (res) => res.arrayBuffer() )
    .then( (res) => {
      console.log(res);
      let buffer = new Uint8Array(res);
      blobChunks.push(buffer);
    });
  }
}

const processChunks = async (blobChunks) => {
  let mp3encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(1, 44100, 128);
  console.log(mp3encoder);
  console.log('chunk stream log', blobChunks); 
  let audioBuffer;
  blobChunks.forEach( (item) => {
    audioBuffer = [...item];
  });

  console.log(audioBuffer);  
    sampleBlockSize = 1152;

    let mp3Data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < audioBuffer.length; i += sampleBlockSize) {
        sampleChunk = samples.subarray(i, i + sampleBlockSize);
        let mp3buffer = mp3encoder.encodeBuffer(sampleChunk);
        if (mp3buffer.length > 0) {
            mp3Data.push(mp3buffer);
        }
    }

  // see if there's any data left
  mp3buffer = mp3encoder.flush();
  if(mp3buffer.length > 0){
    mp3Data.push(mp3buffer);
  }
  console.log('processed stream as mp3', mp3Data);
  let output = new Blob([mp3Data], {type: 'audio/mp3'});
  let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(output);
  chrome.downloads.download({
    saveAs: true,
    url: fileURL
  }, (downloadId) => {
    console.log(downloadId);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
  });
}
```

How I can fix this, is there any error or an alternative to save the buffer in an audio file?

Comment: `audioBuffer` is a normal array. `subarray` only exists on typed arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/subarray

Comment: So I need to convert it to Unit8Array to use the function?